# Encrypting remote laptops with Truecrypt

Tags: passwords, encryption, truecrypt

My current process of encrypting user laptops is to set the password for myself, create a rescue disk, test login and have user set the password to their liking.  I do this while physically with the laptop.

How can I encrypt the remote laptops without knowing the user password and having a rescue disk with a password that only I know while being remote?  I can't remote into the machine until it boots into Windows.

Secondly how can I reset the password remotely without giving the user the rescue disk with my password?  I stress to the users that I can't easily reset their password so don't forget it but I'm bound to have to do a reset at some point.  I feel like I'd need to have the user send me their laptop to not give up the credentials.

Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to encrypt a laptop remotely.  You do understand if you encrypt the laptop, that password, can't be reset right?

Comment: so far as I am aware, this is not possible with full disk encryption, unless you physically possess the device. we usually provide our users an encrypted volume in their user profile space, and allow them to mount it at will, and we do extract a header file with an admin password, so we can let the user change the password and then restore it to the known one if required, but this cannot be done without a running copy of the truecrypt client. http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/changing-passwords-and-keyfiles

Comment: My thought is if the user has to go out of their way to save to the encrypted volume they won't do it. So I use full disk encryption.

Comment: Resetting the password.
I set a known password and create a rescue disk that will allow to set it back to the password that I know that is tied to the rescue disk.  See the warning on http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=rescue-disk